# How can I filter out fields from a Doctrine toMany association?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to prevent certain very expensive Fields from being selected if they are not required.

I have a polygon field in the Database that I only want to select once needed. For collections This field should not be loaded or even show up in the resulting `SELECT * FROM` Section only if selected directly. This is something in generell that I've been searching for. To reduce collection data to a subset of fields to improve sql performance.

For example if the DB is remote I wan't as little information as possible being transferred from the sql server to the php server.

In the case of geometrical data these individual fields can end up being huge.

I know that I can filter the collections after the fact. I'm using Apigility with the FilterInterface already. This helps minimise the data transferred from the php server to the client but not from mysql server to the php server.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ContactSearchprofile", mappedBy="contact", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=false)
 */
private $searchprofiles;
public function getSearchprofiles() {return $this->searchprofiles;} // will select everything
```

Internally it should only do a `repo->select("The, Fields, I, Want")->where('id = :contact_id');` instead of a `select("*")`.

Comment: Did you try marking the Association as [EXTRA_LAZY](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) ? Sounds like your use-case: `Even in a simple scenario like a blog. where posts can be commented, you always have to assume that a post draws hundreds of comments.`

Comment: In this case its not a association that is the issue, instead its an expensive DB "Field" that only needs to be selected at certain times.

Comment: That's why you mark those associations as extra lazy: so they don't get loaded until accessed. (a "OneToMany" is an association, if you mean a regular "json" doctrine type or something, please update your question).